# Google sheet script removes duplicates but removes time from timestamp - Barcode Scanner

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, barcode-scanner

I got this google sheet app I'm working on and everything is working great except that the bottom script is removing my timestamp time. I tried changing a few things but I can't make it stop removing the time.

[image]

```
 function removeDups(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const rng = sh.getRange("A2:O");
  const raw_data = rng.getValues().reverse();
  rng.setValues(raw_data);
  rng.removeDuplicates([11,15]);
  const sorted_rng= sh.getRange("A2:O");
  //  const sorted_data = sorted_rng.getValues().reverse();
  const sorted_data = sorted_rng.getValues().reverse();
  sorted_rng.setValues(sorted_data); 
   DeleteBlankRows()
}


function DeleteBlankRows(){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var Raw = 1; Raw < sh.getLastRow() ; Raw++)
    {
        if( sh.getRange('A'+Raw).getValue() == '')
        {
            sh.deleteRow(Raw) //deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
        }
     }
     sh.getRange("B2:B").clear();
     sh.getRange("L2:L").clear();
     sh.getRange("M2:M").clear();
      }
```

**Update:** Google Custom Form (I let the client scan a barcode. He fills out the form and submits it. Because it is a custom form it doesnt have a way to edit the response like in the original google form so I auto generate a random code to go along with the form and when the user hits back on the web page it is using the same code. At the spreadsheet I have the scripts on the submit trigger to remove duplicates by keeping the latest response with the same code. That's when the response timestamp gets the time stripped off)
[Check out the sample video for the barcode scanner app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-iLJO1s7tc)

Comment: In your situation, I thought that when you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue, it will help understand your current issue. Or, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? Because, from your question, I cannot know the value type and the cell format. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2):

The values in the affected column continue to include the time value. Use [Range.setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) to format them so the time value is shown, like this:

```js
  sorted_rng.setValues(sorted_data).setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss');
```

In the event the data includes numbers other than date times, you can use `.offset()` to specify which columns to format.

Comment: This answer worked except that it changed my values in another column where the values were quantities to date format and I could not recover the original values. On the other hand I noticed that my original timestamp column have the time value when I clicked inside the cell. To fix it I added   `code``  var column = sh.getRange("A2:A");
  column.setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss');   `code`` at the end of the script.

Comment: It would nice if there was something like  `code`` setValues(data).dataColumn[1].setNumberFormat() `code``